# How to keep header & footer same if I want to keep front end in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to build my website using Javascript for front end and PHP for backend. I want to know how can I keep header & footer same on all pages if I am using javascript for client side. I can do it with php very well. But, is it possible with javascript or html also. Or there is any way to mix both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the general way would be using php's `include` or `require`  statements.

but if you want to use javascript ,you may want to use ajax calls to get html for headers and footers. although it would be inefficient, considering you'll be making several requests to the server for not just the html of headers and footers but also for any resources required by them . Better choice would be to use php and load the site from server at once.

Comment: Ok. Please tell me one more thing. If I save my first page as index.php, will javascript file be loaded into it when I give the link.

Comment: sure why not php is served up as html to the browser

Answer (score 0):

use php like this instread of javascript. Create 2 files, `heared.php`, `footer.php`

Keep all your header and footer code in respective files.

Now in each page you use

```
include("path to header.php");// for header
include("path to footer.php");//for footer
```